# Managed DirectX reporting incorrect screen resolutions - can't do 1920x1080?

Tags: c#, direct3d, managed

I came across this problem when trying to run my Managed DirectX program in full screen.  It runs just fine in 1920x1080 (native resolution) as a borderless window, but when I try to create a full screen 1920x1080 device I get an "Error In The Application" exception.  But it worked in 800x600 fullscreen, so I examined the values of **Manager.Adapters.Default.SupportedDisplayModes** and the highest resolution supported is 1600x1024, which does work.  It doesn't offer any modes with 1920 width.

I can't find anything on Google about this problem.  I have an nVidia GeForce GT540M and Windows 7.  Does anyone know anything about this?  Is there a fix?

Further notes:
Under DirectX Caps Viewer, 
DXGI 1.1 Devices\Outputs\Display Modes - it does show 1920x1080, but under
Direct3D9 Devices\Display Modes - it does not show 1920x1080.
I presume MDX uses DX9 as its backend?  But why would DX9 not support 1920x1080?

Comment: I should note that the resolutions reported aren't "incorrect", all of them that I tried are supported, it's just that it's missing the native resolution, 1920x1080.

Comment: Prorbably it's because of the pixel format? FullHD may not be supported for all of them.

Comment: This is likely as you noticed because that resolution is not exposed for Direct3D 9 which is something that the driver can choose to do.  Note: Managed DirectX 1.1 is ancient and deprecated. You should consider moving to SlimDX (which is intended as a more supported version of the original MDX), SharpDX, or some other managed layer for Direct3D access. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/12/09/directx-and-net.aspx) blog post for more information.